# How to compare a string Column without disturbing Indexes

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am having an issue that i have to compare a string column with any value inserted by a user.

Values in column can be in any of formats below; and string cannot be more than 19 characters

```
00000000000
(000) 000-0000
000-000-0000
22222222222222
000 000 00000
000 000 0000
000-000-0000
000-000-00000
00 00 000 0000
000000000000
0000 0000 000
```

The problem is that the data we have contains so many formats and we cannot handle all while comparison in sqlserver as I have some limitation while querying that I can't use any scalar function in where clause as it will disturb indexes and so as performance.

The only option I have is to handle it through C# code.

Can any one help me and guide me in making a generic function in C# which would handle all of the cases mentioned above and other which can be possible?

Comment: Can the data be of any length? Are the spaces, brackets and dashes significant?

Comment: Both existing answers are correct (and the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to add new column that contains normalized value for the formatted value. The normalized value is simply the original value without the unimportant characters (space, bracket, etc.)

when user provide a new input, normalize it and compare it against the normalized value in the database using query.

When you save the data to the database, save both original value and normalized value.

Answer (score 1):

The data looks like it could be phone numbers. If that's the case then the spaces, brackets and dashes aren't significant. So you could strip them out and be left with strings composed solely of digits.

You should be able to compare this normalised form far more easily.

If it's important to retain the format entered by the user, store the normalised form as a separate column in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that '(',')',' ' and '-' can be ignored

```
public class ColumnComparer : IEqualityComparer<string> {
     private static readonly string[] remove = {"(",")"," ","-"};
     public bool Equal(string x, string y){
          //remove ignorable characters;
          var tempX = string.Concat(x.Split(remove,StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmptyEntries));
          var tempY = string.Concat(y.Split(remove,StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmptyEntries));
          return tempX == tempY;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(string x){
          return string.Concat(
               x.Split(remove,StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmptyEntries)
               ).GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

the split and concat might seem a little weird but it's usually the fastest way to remove unwanted characters from a string. There used to be a question on exactly that topic but it seems to have been removed.